# What caused this SEGV_ACCERR crash on ipad 2 os 6.1

Tags: ios, crash

My app has random crashes. This is one of the crash logs:

```
    0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3c2075b0 objc_msgSend (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 16
    1 UIKit 0x362d8d88 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions (in UIKit) + 128
    2 UIKit 0x362a03f4 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] (in UIKit) + 392
    3 UIKit 0x3648da38 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 (in UIKit) + 48
    4 UIKit 0x361c482e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks (in UIKit) + 218
    5 UIKit 0x361c3292 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate (in UIKit) + 1274
    6 UIKit 0x361ce1e6 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] (in UIKit) + 766
    7 UIKit 0x361cddb2 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] (in UIKit) + 90
    8 UIKit 0x361bb800 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] (in UIKit) + 380
    9 UIKit 0x361bb11a _UIApplicationHandleEvent (in UIKit) + 6154
    10 GraphicsServices 0x37eaf5a2 _PurpleEventCallback (in GraphicsServices) + 590
    11 GraphicsServices 0x37eaf1d2 PurpleEventCallback (in GraphicsServices) + 34
    12 CoreFoundation 0x34388172 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION (in CoreFoundation) + 34
    13 CoreFoundation 0x34388116 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 (in CoreFoundation) + 138
    14 CoreFoundation 0x34386f98 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 1384
    15 CoreFoundation 0x342f9ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 356
    16 CoreFoundation 0x342f9d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 104
    17 GraphicsServices 0x37eae2ea GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 74
    18 UIKit 0x3620f300 UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 1120
    19 MyHD 0x0000394e main (in MyHD) (main.m:15)
```

Comment: This crash log is pretty much meaningless (all it says is that a gesture recognizer failed somewhere).  You need to do some debugging first.

Comment: Most likely the gesture's target has been deallocated so it is trying to send its events to a garbage object.

Comment: Post some code dude...